# How did the equation $|A- \lambda I| = 0$ came for finding Eigen values of a Matrix

Tags: matrices

Does anyone know how this equation came.I was studying about Eigenvalues and a doubt that arised was how could the equation $(A- \lambda)V = 0$ become $|A- \lambda I| = 0$.

Comment: As you proabably already know, the eigenvector of a square matrix $M$ is a non-zero vector $v$ that, when the matrix multiplies $v$, gives the same result as when some scalar $\lambda$ multiplies it. Basilcally saying that $Mv=\lambda v$. Now, it's a fundamental result of linear algebra that an equation like $Mv=0$ has a non=zero solution iff the determinant $det(M)$ of the matrix $M$ is zero. It follows then that the eigenvalues of $M$ are exactly these $\lambda$ that satisfy $det(M-\lambda I) = 0$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that an equation $Av = 0$ only has a non-zero solution for $v$ if $\det A = 0$ (why?).

So suppose you have $Av = \lambda v$, so $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$. Rewriting this, we see $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$.This has only a non-zero solution for $v$ if $\det (A-\lambda I) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your
$$(A-\lambda)V = 0$$
is actually
$$\exists V, V\ne 0: (A-\lambda)V = 0$$
I.e. $(A-\lambda I)$ isn't injective, i.e. $(A-\lambda I)$ is singular.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the equation should actually be $(A - \lambda I)V = 0 $ to start with.  But think about it: $V$ is our eigenvector, and eigenvectors *can't* be the $0$ vector.  If $(A - \lambda I)$ were an invertible matrix, then the only vector $V$ that satisfies $(A - \lambda I)V = 0$ is the $0$ vector $V = 0$ since you should just multiply both sides by the inverse of $(A - \lambda I)$.  Specifically, we would have $$V = (A - \lambda I)^{-1} 0 = 0 $$

So, if any eigenvectors exist, it will have to be when $(A - \lambda I)$ is not invertible (since otherwise $V = 0$).  But then, that means that the determinant of $(A - \lambda I)$ must be zero since if it is nonzero, the matrix is invertible, and $V$ must then equal $0$.

Comment: what I would like to know is how the term $I$ came in the equation because really the equation only has $(A- \lambda)V = 0$

Comment: @justin I understand your question, and it is a good one. It doesn't really make sense to talk about a matrix $A$ minus a number $\lambda$.  So we **define** $A - \lambda$ to mean $A - \lambda I$, because when we do it this way, it means we are subtracting $\lambda$ from each entry in the diagonal of $A$.  It makes sense to talk about $A - \lambda I$ since this is the difference of two matrices.  And $I$ is kind of like the number "$1$", but with matrices.

Comment: @Justin Here is a different line of reasoning.  Suppose we have $A v = \lambda v$.  Then $Av - \lambda v = 0$.  But for any vector $v$, since $I$ acts kind of like "$1$" with matrices, we have $v = Iv$ (this is kind of like saying the number $3 = 1*3$).  Then that means $Av - \lambda v = 0$ is really $A v - \lambda I v = 0$.  And from here, we can factor out a $v$ to get $(A - \lambda I)v = 0$.  Does this help?

Comment: okay now got it.But why does it only subtract only the diagonal elements in A but no other elements in A.

Comment: @justin Does my second comment answer your question about the diagonal elements?  If not, I can explain further, just let me know when you get a chance.  By the way, you have to remember that the identity matrix $I$ is the matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal and $0$'s everywhere else.  So in the $2 \times 2$ case, $I = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: But isn't identity matrix used in case of multiplication.Can it be used in subtraction?

Comment: @justin The identity matrix is a matrix, and as long as the dimensions of the other matrix are the same as the identity matrix, then yes you can subtract them.  You subtract them by subtracting each entry in one matrix from the corresponding entry in the other matrix.  Since the identity matrix has only $0$ off of the diagonal, the only entries in the other matrix that are affected are the diagonal entries.  What I meant by the dimensions matching is that you can't subtract $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ from $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @justin Since the dimensions don't match.  But if the dimensions match, you can always subtract two matrices from each other.

Comment: okay that's right.But if we subtract an identity matrix from any matrix(A) whether it would retain the matrix A.

Comment: @justin It won't retain $A$ because the identity matrix has $1$'s on the diagonal.  For example, if we consider the $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, and let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 6 \\ 11 & 19 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, then $A - I = \begin{bmatrix} 5 - 1 & 6 - 0 \\ 11 - 0 & 19 - 1 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 6 \\ 11 & 18 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: :Is it possible to do that(subtraction) without doing it on boths sides(L.H.S & R.H.S).

Comment: @justin I'm not sure I understand what you mean about doing the subtraction on both sides.  Both sides of what?  We had two matrices, $A$ and $I$, and we computed the matrix $(A - I)$.

Comment: :I meant 'both sides' of this equation:$(A- \lambda)V = 0$.But whether we could multiply $I$ with an vector V.

Comment: @Justin Well, I think we should stop thinking about the equation as $(A - \lambda)V = 0$.  Because technically, as we said, $A - \lambda$ doesn't make sense.  Let's stick with how we explained it earlier.  So you have $\, AV = \lambda V$.  Then $AV - \lambda V = 0$.  But for any vector $V$, $V = IV$ (since "$I$" acts like the number $1$, but with matrices, and we know for any number $a$, $a = 1a$).  Then the equation is really $AV - \lambda IV = 0$, and now we can factor out a $V$ to get $(A - \lambda I)V = 0$.  Does every step here make sense?

Comment: :okay now got it.but do you know how to represent a 2D-vector as a matrix,should we use a $2\times1$ matrix or $1\times2$ matrix.

Comment: @justin a column vector is a $2 \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @justin Similarly, an N-dimensional column vector is just an $N \times 1$ matrix.  And our $V$ in your equation is a column vector.

Comment: :I really couldn't understand slide number:25 in the given link: http://1drv.ms/1EnnWAH. I couldn't get how they tunred the vector into matrix